# Visual Studio 2017 multi-line Debug environment variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is VS 2017 (or even earlier versions), when you navigate to `Debug -> <ProjectName> Properties -> Debug tab`, you can add environment variables that your program can then use via `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("var_name")`.

This works great when using a single line value for the variable, but has a character limit.

I have some programs which rely on multi-line variables that are defined on the system they run on when the application is deployed, such as:

`string rsaPrivateKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PRIVATE_KEY");`

However, this is an RSA private keys, and those are multi-line.  I want to be able to debug the application on my workstation, and have those environment variables declared in my VS 2017, and not hard-coded so that the logic that uses these variables can actually succeed.

Has anyone ran into this, and can you provide an alternative for declaring multi-line environment variables for Debugging purposes which will not be committed to source code?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
string rsaPrivateKey;
string rsaPrivateKeyPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PRIVATE_KEY_Path");
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(rsaPrivateKeyPath ))
{
        rsaPrivateKey = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Maybe my question was misunderstood.  There is no "file" that holds this value, it is an environment variable, and for a good reason.  It especially plays nicely when using Docker containers which are agnostic to this value, and the Docker orchestration platform injecting these variables into the container.  This allows for one docker image, that is completely unaware of what the RSA private key is.  It just knows it should find it via an environment variable.

Comment: I see. You are right you wouldn't want to include all of your private keys in all environments. This gives your shady developers access to production keys. ;) Sarcasm aside, I see your problem. I will continue to think on this.